# How to reset database for specific class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello i know you can run rake db:reset. But how does one reset a specific database?

I just want to reset the database for Items class.

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table_name}")`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can delete using SQL

`Model.delete_all` to delete all the data of that particular model.

2. delete by calling each model's destroy method.

`Model.destroy_all`